# taglib link errors

Tags: c++, taglib

I m using taglib for one of my projects . The Debug/Release library is build using MSVC 10. On compiling the code with the library in taglib/taglib/Release some linker error are thrown .

```
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class TagLib::AudioPropertie
s * __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::audioProperties(void)const " (__imp_?audioProperties@FileRef@TagLib@@QEBAPEAVAudioProp
erties@2@XZ) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::getMetaDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,st
ruct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getMetaDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@
DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl TagLib::Stri
ng::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@TagLib@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::getMetaDa
taOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getMetaDataOfF
ile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char
,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl TagLib::String::to8Bit(bool)const " (__imp_?to8
Bit@String@TagLib@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_N@Z) referenced in function
 "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::getMetaDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class s
td::allocator<char> >)" (?getMetaDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator
@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl TagLib::File
Ref::~FileRef(void)" (__imp_??1FileRef@TagLib@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::getMet
aDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getMetaData
OfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class TagLib::Tag * __cdecl
TagLib::FileRef::tag(void)const " (__imp_?tag@FileRef@TagLib@@QEBAPEAVTag@2@XZ) referenced in function "struct Meta
Data __cdecl ID3::getMetaDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator
<char> >)" (?getMetaDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z
)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl TagLib::FileRef
::isNull(void)const " (__imp_?isNull@FileRef@TagLib@@QEBA_NXZ) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3:
:getMetaDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getM
etaDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::Fil
eRef(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (__imp_??0FileRef@TagLib@@QEAA@VFileName
@1@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@1@@Z) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::getMetaDataOfFile(class
 std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getMetaDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AU
MetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
id3.cpp.1.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileName::Fi
leName(char const *)" (__imp_??0FileName@TagLib@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) referenced in function "struct MetaData __cdecl ID3::
getMetaDataOfFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getMe
taDataOfFile@ID3@@YA?AUMetaData@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

I m only including tag.lib from taglib/taglib/Release folder . Is there some other library I m missing out?

Comment: How did you build TagLib? Do you have a static or dynamic version of the library?

Comment: the problem was taglib library was 32 bit and I was using 64 bit msvc. Thanks anyway :)